# Failing to add a builder to my eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to add a new builder to an eclipse project and I am having a problem.

The new builder is an external program.

This is what I have done:
I have created a new program configuration in the external tools.
After creating it I have tested it by making it run - it worked OK.
Than, I have opened the project properties and under "Builders" section I have selected "import".
I have selected my program configuration from the list.

The error was: "Specified container for launch configuration does not exist."

Does anybody knows what this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of error has been seen for instance [with m2eclipse](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-728), and then described in the [bug 247940](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=247940)

It seems a custom builder could not be defined on an *imported* project (as opposed to a project directly created in the eclipse workspace).
So if your `.project` and `.classpath` are defined in an external directory (external to the eclipse workspace), that may be the cause... and this is not yet addressed by eclipse3.5.

Comment: i imported a project into eclipse and checked copy in workspace still my external builder not working and give these errors.   Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'Video_Fx_Testing'.
The file does not exist for the external tool named New_Builder.
The file does not exist for the external tool named New_Builder.

Comment: @nee it is best to ask a new question,  with the exact version os OS, java, eclipse and maven: this answer was written 5 years ago.